# Add default caption to Instagram iOS Hook camera

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I wonder if there is any parameter to specify a default caption for the Instagram iOS hook instagram://camera.
https://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

I'd prefer to use the straight hook, and not the Document Interaction APIs, as I don't want to manage pic files in my app.

Thanks in advance, E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify caption anymore via hooks, it was possible before, but Instagram removed the option to pass caption.